# how to get the color from GradientDrawable

Tags: android

First, I set the green color to be the background of the View mIcon,

```
View mIcon = findViewById(R.id.xxx);

GradientDrawable gdraw = (GradientDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundbtn_white_normal);
gdraw.setColor(Color.GREEN);
mIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(gdraw);
```

Then, I don't know how to get the color from this View's background... there's no getColor() 
function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following class works fine for me so far.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
...

// it's the same with the GradientDrawable, just make some proper modification to make it compilable
public class ColorGradientDrawable extends Drawable {
    ...
    private int mColor; // this is the color which you try to get
    ...
    // original setColor function with little modification
    public void setColor(int argb) {
        mColor = argb;
        mGradientState.setSolidColor(argb);
        mFillPaint.setColor(argb);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    // that's how I get the color from this drawable class
    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }
    ...

    // it's the same with GradientState, just make some proper modification to make it compilable
    final public static class GradientState extends ConstantState {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> getColor() API is added to the gradient drawable class in API 24.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html